# scrolling a webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i asked this question here [scroll webpage](https://coderanch.com/t/672578/javascript-open-scroll-webpage)
thats works well for that particular link used in that code..but fails to scroll the page in [link](https://twitter.com/)
how to scroll  using javascript..

```
<button onclick="openwin()">Open and scroll </button>
<script>
function openwin() {
    var winobj = window.open("/about");
    setTimeout(function() {
        winobj.scrollBy(0, 3000);
    }, 2000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: An alternative is using the hashtag operator in a link. Wikipedia does that, when you press one of the links in the table of contents.

Comment: @Hallur Yes... the hashtag (fragment) auto-link to elements by id, but may be also handled through the JS or VBS

Comment: Did you try my answer? May i do something to improve that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will do the trick:

```
<button onclick="opener()">Open and scroll </button>
<script>
function opener() {
    var win = window.open("/node/1");
    win.onload = function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            win.scrollBy(0, 3000);
        }, 2000);
    };
}
</script>
```

Comment: `win.onload` just a callback that fires when the new page loaded.

Comment: That's good, but what if the page loads earlier than the declaration of this event?

Comment: That's just a callback of a new window.

Comment: Yes, but what if the window loads earlier than you declare this event?

Comment: idk, how to avoid it?

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong, I never used popup windows, but what I said can happen, sometimes. I used the Google and the only way to detect the load event is by doing that. But I think it's also possible to check the existence of a property.

Comment: Hmm.. Have not been accepted as a solution... But works!